# docker-compose nginx proxy_pass to upstream containers not behaving as expected

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get a basic reverse-proxy working to handle multiple websites based on [this tutorial][1], but adapting it to use a ***single docker-compose file*** and proxy_pass to ***upstream containers***. This appears to be the most concise way to go about it as it's for my learning / testing server and I will be starting and stopping containers often. I want to get this locked down before I start adding more complex app containers. I'm not confident in which part of the configuration I should be forwarding ports because most of the questions and tutorials online are not using upstream containers.

EDIT - default server was not listening on 443, fixing this removed one confusion. Now I am only getting the expected index.html from `x.x.x.x/` and the reverse-proxy custom 404 page from `x.x.x.x/site1` or `x.x.x.x/site2` (or anything else)

From what I've read, ports are handled internally by docker as long as the containers are linked (on the same docker network) and even the expose statement is not required in `docker-compose.yml` so long as the container is started with `docker-compose up`

And I've tried forwarding custom ports to the containers with this in docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
  - 8081:443
```

and this in nginx `default.conf`

```
upstream docker-site1 {
    server website1-container:8081;
}
```

But this gives me **502 Bad Gateway**

I am using named containers and external networks to keep names static, in an effort to keep inter-container networking separate from the host, and to take advantage of Docker features in that regard.

I've spent two days on this now and I really need some direction to keep from going around in circles!

EDIT- still going around in circles. Updated default.conf thanks to lmsec, and also added /site1 to the volume path in docker-compose.yml

My docker-compose.yml (in the top level directory) **EDITED - my best working config**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy/
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    hostname: reverse-proxy

    networks:
      - public
      - website1
      - website2

    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443


  site1_app:
    build:
      ./site1/
    volumes:
      - ./site1/html:/usr/share/nginx/html/site1
    container_name: website1-container
    hostname: website1-container
    networks:
      - website1
 
  site2_app:
    build:
      ./site2/
    volumes:
      - ./site2/html:/usr/share/nginx/html/site2
    container_name: website2-container
    hostname: website2-container
    networks:
      - website2

networks:
  public:
    external: true
  website1:
    external: true
  website2:
    external: true
```

Dockerfile in ./proxy/

```
FROM nginx:1.20-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./backend-not-found.html /var/www/html/backend-not-found.html
COPY ./index.html /var/www/html/index.html

#  Proxy and SSL configurations
COPY ./includes/ /etc/nginx/includes/
# Proxy SSL certificates
COPY ./ssl/ /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/
```

the website Dockerfiles only contain `FROM nginx:1.20-alpine`

default.conf in ./proxy/ **EDITED - My most working config, doesn't link JS,CSS,Images**

```
# Default
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
    
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name _;
  root /var/www/html;

  charset UTF-8;

  # Path for SSL config/key/certificate
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/proxy.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/proxy.key;
  include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;


  error_page 404 /backend-not-found.html;
  location = /backend-not-found.html {
    allow   all;
  }

  location / {
    index index.html;
  }
  location /site1 {
    include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://website1-container;
  }
  location /site2 {
    include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://website2-container;
  }


  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

proxy.conf in ./proxy/includes/

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

Each website container has its own network which it shares with the proxy container.

```
 {
    "Name": "website1",
    "Id": "9477470a8689d08776b38c4315882caff75573b7244f77091aa5e5438804ce36",
    "Created": "2021-06-21T02:52:25.402118801Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "192.168.160.0/20",
                "Gateway": "192.168.160.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "7c1a8b62864642afd5366ef88d762e4c5450eee02acb8c3f1890444b59379340": {
            "Name": "website1-container",
            "EndpointID": "f04d96343737574ca869270954461774f731851b781120119c21e02c0aa9968e",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:a0:02",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.160.2/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "a88326952fb5f25f9084eb038f22f56b7331032a5ba71848ea6ada677a2ed998": {
            "Name": "reverse-proxy",
            "EndpointID": "b0c97c7f8dfe0febddbd6668481a009cce0c4f20dae3c3d3280dad0069c90394",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:a0:03",
            "IPv4Address": "192.168.160.3/20",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
```

I can access the website containers through this network and even get index.html with curl:
`sudo docker exec reverse-proxy curl 192.168.160.2/site1/index.html`

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a sample "site1" response</h1>
  </body>
</html>
100   142  100   142    0     0  20285      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23666
```

I'm marking this question closed. I have come to the conclusion that recent versions of docker do not require any special port forwarding when using proxy_pass to a docker container, although if required it can be done in docker-compose and nginx default.conf - as lmsec answers explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [..] in which part of the configuration I should be **forwarding ports** [..] using upstream containers.

You may do it in the upstream definition (abstract from [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) below) :

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    # [..]
}
```

> [..] when I request my server's root x.x.x.x, I get website1 and when I request x.x.x.x/site1 I get a 404 error.

You did not define a `default_server` for https (443), so the **first server is used as default** for 443. (Not sure about why you get a 404.)

> never got a response from website2

You'll need to request `site2` to get a response from it (because of `server_name site2;`). For testing purpose, you can put it in you hosts file.

```
site1     127.0.0.1
site2     127.0.0.1
```

---

Here are some other keys to begin faster with nginx-as-a-proxy :

- `server_name` acts like a requests filter ;
- use `proxy_pass http://docker-site1/;` (with the trailing `/`) so that `/example` goes to `http://docker-site1/example`, not `http://docker-site1` ;
- you may proxy to different hosts or upstreams *based on the URI* (example below : `/site2` and `/site3`).

```
server {
  # Filter requests having 'Host: site1' (ignore the others)
  server_name site1;

  location / {
    # Send everything beginning with '/' to docker-site1
    proxy_pass http://docker-site1/;
  }

  location /site2/ {
    # Send everything beginning with '/site2/' to docker-site2
    #   removing the leading `/site2`
    proxy_pass http://docker-site2/;
  }

  location /site3/ {
    # Send everything beginning with '/site3/' to docker-site3
    #   keeping the leading `/site2`
    proxy_pass http://docker-site3/site3/;
  }
}

server {
  # do something else if the requested Host is site2
  server_name site2;  
}
```

(Of course?) this also works without `upstream`, with your servers' adresses in the `proxy_pass` instead of the `upstream` identifier.

---

EDIT - **Bonus: Docker(-compose) ports and networking**

```
site1_app:
  ports:
    - 8081:443
```

- from "outside" Docker, you'll access `site1_app`'s 443 port from `localhost:8081` (or `x.x.x.x:8081`)
- from another container on the **same network**, you'll access `site1_app`'s 443 port from `site1_app:443`* (or `https://site1_app`)

(Let's imagine `site1_app` also listens on port 80) :

- from "outsite" Docker, you can't access `site1_app`'s 80 port : it is not forwarded (here, only 443 is)
- from another container on the **same network**, you'll access `site1_app`'s 80 port from `site1_app:80`* (or `http://site1_app`)

*Not sure this works with `docker-compose`'s `version: '2'`, but it does with `version: '3.9'`.

The following lines you wrote allow you to call `website1_container` instead of `site1_app` :

```
container_name: website1-container 
hostname: website1-container
```

---

So if you do :

```
# 3
upstream docker-site1 {
    server website1-container:8081;
}
server {
  # 1
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name site1;

  # [..] SSL config/key/certificate

  location / {
    # 2
    proxy_pass http://docker-site1/;
  }
```

Supposing you're setting the request header to `Host: site1` (thanks to your `hosts` file or forging the request headers yourself) :

1. the request, HTTP or HTTPS arrives to the `site1` block
2. it gets proxied to `http://docker-site1/` (*http*)
3. `docker-site1` is resolved as the server group containing only one server : `website1-container:8081`
4. The container `site1_app` receives the request on its `8081` port (not `443`).
5. Even *if* it did, `site1_app` probably wants HTTPS on the `443` port.

So you should :

1. Use the internal port instead of external,
2. Check that you send HTTP (resp. HTTPS) to a port awaiting for HTTP (resp. HTTPS)

Comment: Thanks, this helped my understanding of the nginx config. I was able to get access to my websites by putting them in location blocks in the default server. I removed site1 and site2 server sections, and added 443 & ssl config to the default server. In this way no port needs to be specified in the upstream config.... however, adding only port 443 to upstream will reject 80/http requests.  I still need to get separate server blocks in nginx config to work....

Comment: EDIT, I previously accepted this answer because my browser cache had me thinking everything was working.  It was not. I still can't get server blocks working in nginx default.conf :(

Comment: Thanks again lmsec, I would like to accept your answer as it did get my test setup working, however I'm still none the wiser when it comes to docker container ports.  Maybe I should re-frame my question?

Comment: Nice to know it helped, I added some clarifications on Docker ports forwarding.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working my way through this... so just for clarification, am I correct that; 1. I don't need upstream unless I want to something special, I can simply proxy_pass to the container? 2. As was my intent, I don't need to forward 80 or 443 on different ports because docker allows containers to listen on the same port, as "servers" on the docker network?

Comment: ...also, I'm now using docker-compose version: '3.6'

Comment: I give up! I can get to my docker images by location /site1.  I can set up a dummy file in the reverse-proxy container html/site1/index.html and get to that by server { server_name site1 } but I can't get to the docker image that way.  I have a problem with proxy settings now that I have tested the "location /site1" config with a proper website and it returns HTML but  CSS+JS and images are all 404. I will ask a new question about that.